# Saving whole data in a list at once and then displaying one by one or changing the html content of single div

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating an app using "vue.js" in which there are few videos and there is a button, video title and video description for each video, so that when a user clicks on the button it will only display the related video, its title and the description but the video titles and descriptions of all other videos will be hidden. Now there are two ways to do this: 
1. By creating the list of all the video titles and descriptions with default display property as none and then changing the display property to block of only one video title and description on the button click. For ex:

```js
onBtnClick: function(event, index) {
    var videoContainer = "#videoContainer" + index;
    $(videoContainer).css("display", "block);
    }
```

```css
.container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div v-for="(video, index) in json._videos" id="'videoContainer'+index" class="container">
  <div v-if="video.title">{{ video.title }}</div>
  <div v-if="video.decription">{{ video.decription }}</div>
</div>

<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button v-for="(video, index) in json._videos" id="'button'+index" v-on:click="onBtnClick($event,index)">{{ video.buttonText }}</button>
</div>
```

2. By creating the single video container and then changing the html content of the video title and description using v-html directive. For ex:

```js
onBtnClick: function(event, index) {
  getVideoTitle(index);
  getVideoDescription(index);
}

getVideoTitle: function(index) {
  return json._videos[index].title;
}

getVideoDescription: function(index) {
  return json._videos[index].description;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="'videoContainer'+index" class="container">
  <div v-if="json._videos" v-html="getVideoTitle()"></div>
  <div v-if="json._videos" v-html="getVideoDescription()"></div>
</div>

<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button v-for="(video, index) in json._videos" id="'button'+index" v-on:click="onBtnClick($event,index)">{{ video.buttonText }}</button>
</div>
```

Guys please tell me which one is the better approach and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two Vue components: VideoList and single Video.

In your Video component you should have attribute "isVisible" (or with other name, if you want), which will be set from VideoList component for the specifig Video component.

This approach grant you ability to separate your logic and gives full control for every single video and for all set of such videos.

Here is the full working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/yh1xrk27/22/

```
var VideoList = Vue.component('video-list', {
    template: $('#video-list').html(),
    data: function () {
        return {
            videos: [
            ]
        };
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.videos = [
            {
                title: 'Video 1',
                description: 'The first video',
                isVisible: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Video 2',
                description: 'The second video',
                isVisible: false
            }
        ];
    },
    methods: {
        show: function (index) {
            var self = this;
            for (var key in this.videos) {
                this.videos[key].isVisible = (key == index);
            }
        }
    }
});

var VideoItem = Vue.component('video-item', {
    template: $('#video-item').html(),
    props: [
        'fields'
    ],
    data: function () {
        return {
            title: '',
            description: '',
            isVisible: false
        };
    },
    created: function () {
        this.title = this.fields.title;
        this.description = this.fields.description;
        this.isVisible = this.fields.isVisible;
    }
});

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**Answer on author's comment**:

You can get your date from any desired source, it's not the problem.

Also you do not have to define all fields for every single video. Every field in VideoItem have deafult value and when you assign attributes from property "fields", you should just check definition of every field. For example:

Replace this:

```
created: function () {
    this.title = this.fields.title;
    this.description = this.fields.description;
    this.isVisible = this.fields.isVisible;
}
```

On this:

```
created: function () {
    this.title = typeof this.fields.title !== 'undefined' ? this.fields.title : 'SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE';
    this.description = typeof this.fields.title !== 'undefined' ? this.fields.description ? 'SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE';
    this.isVisible =  typeof this.fields.title ? this.fields.isVisible : false; // or true, depends on you
}
```

Or you can create separate method for setting data about videos and call this method in `created` hook of the component VideoList:

```
methods: {
    ...
    setData: function(){
        this.title = typeof this.fields.title !== 'undefined' ? this.fields.title : 'SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE';
        this.description = typeof this.fields.title !== 'undefined' ? this.fields.description ? 'SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE';
        this.isVisible =  typeof this.fields.title ? this.fields.isVisible : false; // or true, depends on you
    }
}
```

And in your VideoList component you can load information about videos from anywhere, from internal or external resource. For example:

```
created: function(){
    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        // load data from some internal resource or paste some external resource link
        url: '/source/videos.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(jsonData){

        // call setData method of this component
        self.setData(jsonData);
        },
    });
}
```

So you don't have any limits about your JSON, do what you want with your raw JSON data and paste it in VideoList component, that's all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Although your solution is more vue.js focused(which is good) but I am receiving all the titles and descriptions from json file in which I don't have isVisible kind of attribute but if I follow your approach then either I have to define it in the json file or I have to define all the titles and descriptions in mounted function which will make the js file too long as I will use around 30 videos and all of them have long descriptions. What do you think?

Comment: Alexander and @Saurabh Ok I'll use this approach and thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest one more variable, use a [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) option of vue, and have a data variable for your videos. The benefit is that you can use the same variable at multiple places and it is reactive as well, i.e. change in that variable will be reflected in the view.

```
data:{ 
   return videos: []
}
methods: {
  onBtnClick: function(event, index) {
    updateVideoTitle(index);
    updateVideoDescription(index);
  }

  updateVideoTitle: function(index) {
    this.videos[index] = Object.assign(this.videos[index], {title: json._videos[index].title});
  }

  updateVideoDescription: function(index) {
    this.videos[index] = Object.assign(this.videos[index], {description: json._videos[index].description});
  }
}
```

and in HTML:

```
<div v-for="(video, index) in videos" id="'videoContainer'+index" class="container">
  <div v-if="video.title">{{ video.title }}</div>
  <div v-if="video.decription">{{ video.decription }}</div>
</div>

<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button v-for="(video, index) in videos" id="'button'+index" v-on:click="onBtnClick($event,index)">{{ video.buttonText }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I am already following the similar approach and I know it works fine but my question is that populating and storing all the titles and descriptions at once and then setting only single video container's display to block or none is the good approach or using only one video container having two divs videoTitle and videoDescription and then updating their values using v-html directive?

Comment: @Aashu.M The example you have given in the code, both looks similar.

Comment: No they are not similar see I am not using v-for directive in the second example instead I have only one video container and I am trying to update the value of title and description divs using v-html directive. So if we inspect the html after page rendering it will only show one video container and not the multiple video containers with display none css property as in the case of first example. Both approaches will work but I am comparing them to get the best performance.

Comment: @Aashu.M OK, in that case I will say you can use the first apprach and create a vue component as suggested in the other answer,